# Tangent plane to the surface and the Taylor polynomial

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Let $f(x,y) = a \sin(x+y^2) + e^{bx+y^2}$, what are the values of $a$ and $b$ such that the tangent plane to the surface $z = f(x,y)$ at $(0,0,f(0,0))$ be horizontal and the second order Taylor polynomial about the origin take the value 1 at the point (0, 1).

I know that if $f(x,y)$ is class $C^{1}$, the tangent plane to the surface $z=f(x,y)$  at the point $(x_0, y_0, f(x_0, y_0))$ is given by:

$z = f(x_0, y_0) + \langle \nabla f(x_0, y_0), ((x/y) - (x_0/y_0))\rangle$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}= \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}= a cos(x+ y^2)+ be^{bx+ y^2}$ and

$\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}= \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}= 2ay cos(x+ y^2)+ 2ye^{bx+ y^2}$.

At (0, 0) those are $\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}= a+ b$ and

$\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}= 0$ while

z(0,0)= 0 so the tangent plane at (0, 0, f(0, 0)) is z= (a+ b)x.